# C# UDP Async Chatting Program - Two-way connection between server and client is not possible

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, udp, chat

I'm making UDP chatting program using WPF.

[image]

I tested this program as follows:

1. Run two identical programs.
2. Select one server and one client by toggling the buttons.
3. Press the connect button on both to bind to the port.
4. Chat 1:1 with each other.

But it doesn't work properly. To be precise, the program that sent the text first operates normally in both transmission and reception. However, the program that sent the text later can send, but the receive function does not work. From the debug results, it seems that `Receive()` is not being called in `asyncResult = client.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());`, but I don't know how to fix it.

Below is the full code. (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace NetworkFinal
{
    public enum Type { Client, Server }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private const int SERVERPORT = 9000;
        private Type type = Type.Server;
        private Thread hThread;

        private UdpClient client;
        private IPEndPoint endPoint;
        private IAsyncResult asyncResult;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string ip = IPTextBox.Text;
            string message = SendTextBox.Text;
            byte[] bytesHeader = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(type == Type.Server ? "S" : "C");
            byte[] bytesMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesHeader.Length + bytesMessage.Length];
            bytesHeader.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
            bytesMessage.CopyTo(bytes, bytesHeader.Length);

            try
            {
                using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient())
                {
                    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), SERVERPORT);
                    client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                    client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, endPoint);

                    PrintChat("나: " + message);
                    SendTextBox.Text = string.Empty;

                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PrintConsole(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            hThread = new Thread(ReceiveThreadFunc);
            hThread.Start();
        }

        private void btnChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (type == Type.Server)
            {
                type = Type.Client;
                TypeLabel.Content = "클라이언트";
            }
            else
            {
                type = Type.Server;
                TypeLabel.Content = "서버";
            }
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            Close();
        }
        
        private void ReceiveThreadFunc()
        {
            try
            {
                if (client != null) throw new Exception("UDP 소켓이 이미 생성되어 있습니다.");

                client = new UdpClient();
                endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, SERVERPORT);
                client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                client.Client.Bind(endPoint);

                PrintConsole(string.Format("Binding Port {0}. Start Listening...", SERVERPORT));
                StartListening();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PrintConsole(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void StartListening()
        {
            asyncResult = client.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
        }

        private void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            if (client == null) return;

            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = client.EndReceive(ar, ref endPoint);
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                if (isValidMessage(message))
                {
                    message = message.Substring(1);
                    PrintChat("상대: " + message);
                }
                StartListening();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PrintConsole(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private bool isValidMessage(string message)
        {
            if (type == Type.Server)
            {
                return message[0].Equals('C');
            }
            else
            {
                return message[0].Equals('S');

            }
        }

        private void PrintChat(string message)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate {
                ChatTextBlock.Text += message;
                ChatTextBlock.Text += "\n";
            }));
        }

        private void PrintConsole(string message)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate {
                ConsoleTextBlock.Text += message;
                ConsoleTextBlock.Text += "\n";
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are closing the client after each send so you cannot receive anything after the connection is closed : client.Close();

Comment: Thank you for leaving a comment. However, the client I close is a local variable declared in btnSend_Click() and is used only for sending messages. The client used for receive is declared as a member variable of MainWindow and is not closed. (It should be closed when the application terminates, but I forgot that code.)

Comment: You have a race condition.  The client uses timers to transfer data from the app to to ethernet interface.  It is part of the timer tick event in the machine.  So you are sending and then closing before the data actual get sent.